# SAS: Merge two plots into one by group

Tags: group-by, sas, sgplot

I have two plots that I would like to merge into one. Each plot represents the proportion of present / not-present observations by their corresponding cumulative test results for the year

So on the plot I would like to see bars, side by side for groups of test scores but counting number of present to not-present

To represent this problem, this is what I have currently:

```
data test_scores;
    do i = 1 to 200;
        score = ranuni(200);
        output;
    end;
    drop i;
run;

data test_scores_2;
    set test_scores;
    if _n_ le 100 then flag = 0;
    else flag = 1;
run;

data test_scores_2_0 test_scores_2_1;
    set test_scores_2;
    if flag = 0 then output test_scores_2_0;
            else if flag = 1 then output test_scores_2_1;
run;

PROC GCHART 
    DATA=test_scores_2_0 
    ;
    VBAR 
    score
    /
    CLIPREF
    FRAME   
    LEVELS=20
    TYPE=PCT
    COUTLINE=BLACK
    RAXIS=AXIS1
    MAXIS=AXIS2
;
RUN;
QUIT;

PROC GCHART 
    DATA=test_scores_2_1
    ;
    VBAR 
    score
    /
    CLIPREF
    FRAME   
    LEVELS=20
    TYPE=PCT
    COUTLINE=BLACK
    RAXIS=AXIS1
    MAXIS=AXIS2
;
RUN;
QUIT;
```

bars should sum up to 100% for present
bars should sum up to 100% for non-present

TIA

Comment: Your example data has some errors and does not appear to output correctly. There are also some unresolved macro variables. Can you take a look at your example data again?

Comment: Fixed, didn't realise I had those macro variables active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`proc sgplot` to the rescue. Use the `group=` option to specify two separate groups. Set the transparency to 50% so one histogram does not cover the other.

```
proc sgplot data=test_scores_2;
    histogram score / group=flag transparency=0.5 binwidth=.05;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: that looks real nice, I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

With `Proc GCHART` you can use `VBAR` options `GROUP=` and `G100` to get bars that represent percent within group.  This is useful when the groups have different counts.

The `SUBGROUP=` option splits the vertical bar according to the different values of the subgroup variable, and produces automatic coloration and legend corresponding to the subgroups.

When the `SUBGROUP` variable (or values) correspond 1:1 to the group the result is a chart with a different color for each group and a legend corresponding to the group.

For example, modify your data so group 1 has a 50 count and group 2 has 150 count:

```
data test_scores;
    do _n_ = 1 to 200;
        score = ranuni(200);
        flag = _n_ > 50;
        output;
    end;
run;

axis1 label=("score");
axis2 ;
axis3 label=none value=none;

PROC GCHART data=test_scores;
  VBAR score
  / levels=10

     GROUP=flag    G100
  SUBGROUP=flag

  SPACE=0 TYPE=PERCENT freq gaxis=axis3 maxis=axis1 ;
run;
```

Output

[image]

Similar chart showing the effect of a subgroup variable with values different than group values.

```
data test_scores;
    do _n_ = 1 to 200;

        subgroup = ceil(5 * ranuni(123));     * random 1 to 5;

        score = ranuni(200);
        flag = _n_ > 50;
        output;
    end;
run;

axis1 label=("score");
axis2 ;
axis3 label=none value=none;

PROC GCHART data=test_scores;
  VBAR score
  / levels=10

     GROUP=flag G100 
  SUBGROUP=subgroup   /* has integer values in [1,5] */

  SPACE=0 TYPE=PERCENT freq gaxis=axis3 maxis=axis1;
run;
```

[image]